# Getting duplicate virtual directory name after hosting application in IIS 8.5+

Tags: web-hosting, iis-8.5

I am hosting my application as 'Add Application' under Default website,and used HTTP Redirect module to navigate particular to domain. It works perfectly as below URL

*WebClient is added in IIS using 'Add application'

e.g. www.abc.com/WebClient/dashboard/home -- original URL

but sometimes we get below URL
e.g. www.abc.com/WebClient/WebClient/dashboard/home -- Faulty URL

You can see in above URL 'WebClient' is repeating twice or sometime it gets multiple times, because of this everything gets break (CSS/JS) and page can not display properly and gives message 404 not found.

I have searched the solution but no success, can any one please help me to come out of this issue.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Stop using "HTTP Redirect" module. Install URL Rewrite module and create your rules.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li, I will check with URL Rewrite... and get back to u..

Comment: Hi Lex Li, I have tried but not able to login in application. Actually I am creating web site and creating application inside that web site, also I have assigned domain name to web site using bindings.

Comment: Hi Lex Li, Please ignore above comment. I have tried, but no success.we have http://demo.com website Also we have web application http://demo.com/webclient. When client hits http://demo.com it should automatically divert to http://demo.com/webclient
e.g. it something as http://demo.com => http://demo.com/webclient. Like to use URL Rewrite for this. Please explain the solution.